# is it possible to add a new tableview in a collapsable TableViewCell?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

i am beginner in iOS and i have a problem i want to add a new TableView in a Collapsable TableViewCell but i am unable to do that & i also want to add a button at the end of the last cell.So can anyone plz guide me?Thanks in advance...

i already tried a lot with a collapsable tableview but i am unable to do that

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Newcell) as? secondTableViewCell
    cell!.namesLabelSecond.text = levelNames[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
    if tableView == self.tableView{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: oldCell, for: indexPath) as! LevelTableViewCell
        cell.labelText.text = levelNames[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Newcell) as? secondTableViewCell
        cell?.namesLabelSecond.text = nameSecond[indexPath.row]
        return cell!

    }
}
```

Comment: code after first "return" will never be executed

Comment: so what i have to do?can you provide any sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample of code, constraints in you tableViewCell for label(top to View, hugging priority 1000), button(top to label, bottom to contentView, height).

```
    typealias ExpandBlock = () -> ()

class ExpandableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var textlabel: UILabel!

    var block: ExpandBlock? = nil

    @IBAction func expandCell(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        textlabel.numberOfLines = sender.isSelected ? 0 : 2
        block?()
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! ExpandableCell
        cell.block = {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
        return cell
    }

}
```